# How can I get the current user name in the C# code behind of Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, windows-authentication

I have a Blazor server app with IIS Windows Authentication where I can get the current user in my razor page with following code, without problem:

```
<AuthorizeView>
        @context.User.Identity.Name
    </AuthorizeView>
```

I need this user info also in the code behind C# Class of the razor page (razor.cs)
I tried this but I always get null as active user:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
namespace WebApplication7.Pages
{  
public partial class Explorer
{
 public System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal User { get; set; }
 public static string CurrentUserName { get; set; }
 protected override async void OnInitialized() // = On Page Load
    {                   
        var authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        CurrentUserName = authenticationState.User.Identity.Name;            
    }
 }
 }
```

I tried to use also 'context.User.Identity.Name' but I get always missing namespace error. What is wrong or missing in my code?

Comment: Request-scoped data should not be `static` btw.

Comment: The environment on the server is different form the environment on the client. How should the server environment KNOW which user is involved? (I am not an expert in this field!), but sending the username with the request to the server seems a simple solution?

Comment: You need to `@inject AuthenticationStateProvider somealias`, and make your method calls on the injection instance alias, not the class name.

Comment: @Luuk Blazor has some crazy voodoo that lets you write code that does indeed run on the client as WASM, but with invisible proxying of data from the server - it's an impressive achievement by Microsoft, but I have my own unrelated reservations.

Comment: @Dai  Excuse me so much, but i am beginner developer. Could you give an example how I can do the request ? Do you mean http request from the code behind page? I'm really blocked at this point.

Comment: @Mdarende If you're a beginner then I think you should stick to traditional SSR (i.e. ASP.NET (Core) MVC using only server-side code: `Controller` classes, `.cshtml` Razor (not Blazor) views, etc) and avoid Blazor for now, because writing for Blazor requires a lot of prior understanding of how all the pieces come together (server-side-code, client-side-code, WASM, the browser sandbox, etc)

Comment: @bennyboy1973  Yes this was the easiest solution i was looking for. It worked perfect.

Comment: @Dai No offense, but I have experience with both MVC and Blazor, and I would recommend Blazor for people new to .net.  The connection between markup and code is much more immediate.

Comment: @Dai I'd also recommend you learn Blazor.  .net allows you to mix / match pretty much any way of doing things, so you will be able to use your MVC experience.  For example, even in Blazor, Identity Scaffolding uses controller / .cshtml.  So you won't lose value from your existing knowledge, but you can gain new tools that are very fun to use.

Comment: When you say "I need this user info also in the code behind C# Class of the razor page (razor.cs)" do you mean in a server side razor page?  Or in a Blazor page code behind file?

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis   I mean in the Blazor page code behind file (Blazor Server app)

Comment: @Mdarende - In that case see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Razor file with two code behind files demonstrating two slightly different methods to get the user.  The page displays the user name and the claims info for the user:

```
@page "/"
<h3>User</h3>
@if (this.user is not null && this.user.Identity is not null)
{
    <div class="p-2 m-2">
        <div class="p-2">
            Name: @user.Identity.Name
        </div>
        @foreach(var claim in this.user.Claims)
        {
        <div class="p-2">
            @claim.Type: @claim.Value
        </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

The first code behind file shows how to use the cascading `Task<AuthenticationState>` (as the `AuthorizeView` component does).

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace BlazorApp3.Pages
{
    public partial  class User: ComponentBase
    {
        [CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> provider { get; set; } = default!;

        private ClaimsPrincipal? user;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var state = await provider;
            // This is the current logged in user
            user = state.User;
        }
    }
}
```

And a second version showing how to use the `AuthenticationStateProvider` DI service:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace BlazorApp3.Pages
{
    public partial  class User: ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject] public AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; } = default!;

        private ClaimsPrincipal? user;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var state = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            // This is the current logged in user
            user = state.User;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also "inject" the service directly into the page like this:

```
@page "/"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
<h3>User</h3>
```

Comment: Might be worth showing how to inject in markup with `@inject` as well.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - NP.  As the question was "I need this user info also in the code behind C# Class of the razor page (razor.cs)", I've show how to do it that way.  I've added your comment at the bottom  for completeness.